# Keras symbolic inputs/outputs do not implement `op`

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm following this tutorial trying to convert a .h5 model to a tensorRT model
[link to the tutorial](https://colab.research.google.com/github/Tony607/tf_jetson_nano/blob/master/Step1_Colab_TensorRT.ipynb#scrollTo=L-Jx1Yq0uejv).

I'm using tensorflow 2.6.0 so I have changed some lines, but I'm stuck in the model freeze block. I'm having this error in these lines:

`input_names = [t.op.name for t in model.inputs]`
`output_names = [t.op.name for t in model.outputs]`

The problem is the same in both lines:

> TypeError: Keras symbolic inputs/outputs do not implement `op`. You may be trying to pass Keras symbolic inputs/outputs to a TF API that does not register dispatching, preventing Keras from automatically converting the API call to a lambda layer in the Functional Model.

As I've said, I'm following this tutorial, but I have an efficientNetB5 model that I trained yesterday, I though it would be enough if I load it into this part of the notebook and start by freezing it, but now I can't continue.

Any idea of what's happening here?

Comment: Hi! Attaching Issue  with same Error Stack Trace . https://github.com/philipperemy/keract/issues/128 . Contrib Support has been removed by 2.x versions . So Could you try again after with                                                     
"from tensorflow.python.compiler.tensorrt import trt_convert as trt"?   Reference :        https://blog.tensorflow.org/2021/01/leveraging-tensorflow-tensorrt-integration.html